# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() hangs on .NET 3.5 but works on .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

The following code hangs when I try to run it on .NET 3.5 (it works when I set the project to .NET 4)

(I've waited like 2 minutes - It seems to freeze)

```
        HttpWebRequest l_oRequest;
        HttpWebResponse l_oResponse;

        if (m_bLoggedIn)
            return true;

        m_oSession = new SSessionIdentifier();
        m_oSession.Cookies = new CookieContainer();

        string l_sHost = "https://website.com";

        // Start the login sequence
        l_oRequest = GetNewRequest(l_sHost, "Login.aspx", m_oSession.Cookies);
        l_oRequest.Timeout = 5000;
        l_oRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
        l_oRequest.Method = "POST";
        l_oRequest.Referer = "https://website.com";

        // Set form parameters
        string l_sFormParameters = "user=" + m_sUsername;

        // Convert them to the HTTP stream
        byte[] l_oRequestBuffer = UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(l_sFormParameters);
        var l_oRequestStream = l_oRequest.GetRequestStream();
        l_oRequestStream.Write(l_oRequestBuffer, 0, l_oRequestBuffer.Length);

        // I'm setting this to false because otherwise i can't get the cookies i want. And I love them cookies!
        l_oRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        // Now start the redirection sequence until we get to what we want
        int l_iDTPos = -1;
        // This line hangs
        l_oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)l_oRequest.GetResponse();
        while (l_oResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
                // Yada Yada
```

This is the GetNewRequest function:

```
    private HttpWebRequest GetNewRequest(string host, string targetUrl, CookieContainer a_oCookieJar)
    {
        HttpWebRequest l_oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(host + targetUrl);
        l_oRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";
        l_oRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        l_oRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        l_oRequest.CookieContainer = a_oCookieJar;

        return l_oRequest;
    }
```

I couldn't find any change between 3.5 and 4 in the documentation. Has anyone ran into such a problem?

Comment: Your `l_sHost` is malformed - "*https:/*website.com" should be "*https://*website.com". Not sure if that's in your code, or just a typo in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hitting this same issue where I was calling a RESTful service using HttpWebRequest and my code worked great in .Net 4+ and hung on the GetResponse() line in .Net 3.5, 3.0. 2.0. I ended up trying the sample code from this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

and got it working in all versions of .Net. I'm guessing I wasn't setting something correct or closing a resource, but for anyone else who hits this give the article a try.

Comment: The thing you probably did different is close the request stream. I have just had the same problem and used your link to that example to see that. .net 4 must close the stream automatically when you call Write()

Answer (score 0):

try using code given in following link, it used Stream class to get repose data for the httpwebrequest made :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1178426.aspx/1

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The link talks about HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream, but my application hangs on getting the response using GetResponse - Which is needed to use GetResponseStream